# MySQL natural sorting with text and numbers

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I have table with item name, for example:

```
...
Cheburashka with detailed ear 10g. (O.Box 5 pcs.)
Cheburashka with detailed ear 12g. (O.Box 5 pcs.)
Cheburashka with detailed ear 4g. (O.Box 5 pcs.)
Skittle with two swivels 20g. (O.Box 5 pcs.)
Skittle with two swivels 6g. (O.Box 5 pcs.)
...
```

And I need:

```
...
Cheburashka with detailed ear 4g. (O.Box 5 pcs.)
Cheburashka with detailed ear 10g. (O.Box 5 pcs.)
Cheburashka with detailed ear 12g. (O.Box 5 pcs.)
Skittle with two swivels 6g. (O.Box 5 pcs.)
Skittle with two swivels 20g. (O.Box 5 pcs.)
...
```

etc, and I need to sort the rows alphabetically, and with value numbers - weight.

SQL Fiddle link - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4cbd8/1

I tried to sort rows with `LENGTH()`, `CAST()`, `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`, but it all failed.

Comment: @Mihai, it's for example :)

Comment: Post some sample data with the desired order in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT item_name
FROM items 
ORDER BY 
reverse(mid(
reverse(mid(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(item_name,',',''),' . ','. '),'r. ','g. '),'d. ','g. '),' g ','g. '),1,instr(replace(replace(replace(replace(item_name,' . ','. '),'r. ','g. '),'d. ','g. '),' g ','g. '), 'g. (')-1)),
instr(reverse(mid(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(item_name,',',''),' . ','. '),'r. ','g. '),'d. ','g. '),' g ','g. '),1,instr(replace(replace(replace(replace(item_name,' . ','. '),'r. ','g. '),'d. ','g. '),' g ','g. '), 'g. (')-1)),' ')
)),
cast(reverse(mid(
reverse(mid(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(item_name,',',''),' . ','. '),'r. ','g. '),'d. ','g. '),' g ','g. '),1,instr(replace(replace(replace(replace(item_name,' . ','. '),'r. ','g. '),'d. ','g. '),' g ','g. '), 'g. (')-1)),1,  
instr(reverse(mid(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(item_name,',',''),' . ','. '),'r. ','g. '),'d. ','g. '),' g ','g. '),1,instr(replace(replace(replace(replace(item_name,' . ','. '),'r. ','g. '),'d. ','g. '),' g ','g. '), 'g. (')-1)),' ')
)) as signed)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4cbd8/73/0)**:

```
|                                                ITEM_NAME |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
|   Load Cheburashka with detailed ear 4g. ( O.Box 5 pcs.) |
|   Load Cheburashka with detailed ear 6d. ( O.Box 5 pcs.) |
|   Load Cheburashka with detailed ear 8g. ( O.Box 5 pcs.) |
|  Load Cheburashka with detailed ear 10g. ( O.Box 5 pcs.) |
|  Load Cheburashka with detailed ear 12g. ( O.Box 5 pcs.) |
| Load Cheburashka with detailed ear 14g . ( O.Box 5 pcs.) |
| Load Cheburashka with detailed ear 16g . ( O.Box 5 pcs.) |
| Load Cheburashka with detailed ear 18g . ( O.Box 5 pcs.) |
| Load Cheburashka with detailed ear 20g . ( O.Box 5 pcs.) |
| Load Cheburashka with detailed ear 22g . ( O.Box 3 pcs.) |
| Load Cheburashka with detailed ear 24g . ( O.Box 3 pcs.) |
| Load Cheburashka with detailed ear 26g . ( O.Box 3 pcs.) |
| Load Cheburashka with detailed ear 28g . ( O.Box 3 pcs.) |
| Load Cheburashka with detailed ear 32g . ( O.Box 3 pcs.) |
| Load Cheburashka with detailed ear 36g . ( O.Box 3 pcs.) |
| Load Cheburashka with detailed ear 40g . ( O.Box 3 pcs.) |
|                  Load Cone with dope 3d. ( O.Box 5 pcs.) |
|                  Load Cone with dope 4g. ( O.Box 5 pcs.) |
|                  Load Cone with dope 6d. ( O.Box 5 pcs.) |
|                 Load Cone with dope, 8g. ( O.Box 5 pcs.) |
|                 Load Cone with dope 10g. ( O.Box 5 pcs.) |
|                 Load Cone with dope 12g. ( O.Box 5 pcs.) |
|                Load Cone with dope 13g . ( O.Box 5 pcs.) |
|                Load Cone with dope 15g . ( O.Box 5 pcs.) |
|                Load Cone with dope 18g . ( O.Box 5 pcs.) |
|               Load Ovsinka with dope 3d. ( O.Box 5 pcs.) |
|              Load Ovsinka with dope, 7g. ( O.Box 5 pcs.) |
|              Load Ovsinka with dope 10g. ( O.Box 5 pcs.) |
|             Load Ovsinka with dope 14g . ( O.Box 5 pcs.) |
|             Load Ovsinka with dope 18g . ( O.Box 5 pcs.) |
|               Load Skittle with dope 6d. ( O.Box 5 pcs.) |
|              Load Skittle with dope, 9g. ( O.Box 5 pcs.) |
|             Load Skittle with dope 14g . ( O.Box 5 pcs.) |
|             Load Skittle with dope 16g . ( O.Box 5 pcs.) |
|             Load Skittle with dope 20g . ( O.Box 5 pcs.) |
|        Load Skittle with two swivels 6d. ( O.Box 5 pcs.) |
|        Load Skittle with two swivels 9g. ( O.Box 5 pcs.) |
|      Load Skittle with two swivels 14g . ( O.Box 5 pcs.) |
|      Load Skittle with two swivels 16g . ( O.Box 5 pcs.) |
|      Load Skittle with two swivels 20g . ( O.Box 5 pcs.) |
|             Oliva cargo with dope, 3.5 g ( O.Box 5 pcs.) |
|               Oliva cargo with dope, 7g. ( O.Box 5 pcs.) |
|            Oliva cargo with dope, 10.5 g ( O.Box 5 pcs.) |
|              Oliva cargo with dope 14g . ( O.Box 5 pcs.) |
|                Thumb load with dope, 2r. ( O.Box 5 pcs.) |
|                 Thumb load with dope 3d. ( O.Box 5 pcs.) |
|                Thumb load with dope, 7g. ( O.Box 5 pcs.) |
|                Thumb load with dope 10g. ( O.Box 5 pcs.) |
```

Comment: this very hard to do, really? in table 10k items with another names, sizes, etc.. and this way not ideal to me :(

Comment: This does exactly what you want.

Comment: What do you mean by "universal approach"? Can you explain better in your question what you actually want. Cause this those the trick with data you provided. If there is data that don't match, let me (us) know what are those data? I (we) can't help you if you don't provide all informations needed to solve your problem.

Comment: I thought I would have a simpler approach, and not knowing all that difficult.

Comment: The fact is that your data are really not normalized. Considering 18g. as example, you have it represented in many ways : 18g. - 18g - 18 g. - 18g . - 18 g - 18d. - 18r. - etc. If it was always 18g. than a lot of `replace` will be not required...

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is kinda ugly, but it seems to work on your sqlfiddle:

```
SELECT item_name

FROM items ORDER BY 
item_name,
cast(substring(item_name,LEAST(
    if (Locate('0',item_name) >0,Locate('0',item_name),999),
    if (Locate('1',item_name) >0,Locate('1',item_name),999),
    if (Locate('2',item_name) >0,Locate('2',item_name),999),
    if (Locate('3',item_name) >0,Locate('3',item_name),999),
    if (Locate('4',item_name) >0,Locate('4',item_name),999),
    if (Locate('5',item_name) >0,Locate('5',item_name),999),
    if (Locate('6',item_name) >0,Locate('6',item_name),999),
    if (Locate('7',item_name) >0,Locate('7',item_name),999),
    if (Locate('8',item_name) >0,Locate('8',item_name),999),
    if (Locate('9',item_name) >0,Locate('9',item_name),999)
  )) as unsigned)
```

Comment: it orders by the first number in the string.  sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4cbd8/34

Comment: I need to sort the rows ALPHABETICALY, and with value numbers.

Comment: I edited the answer.  Orders first alphbetically, then by the value.

Comment: `Load Cheburashka with detailed ear 40g . ( O.Box 3 pcs.)` higher than `Load Cheburashka with detailed ear 4g. ( O.Box 5 pcs.)`, it's wrong

Comment: A dot is misplaced in the sample fiddle so it interprets it as a new category.

Comment: With `ORDER BY item_name` in first place, you are sure that it will not working